# I am attempting to use Python MultinomialNB from sklearn to classify some data but it returns a Value Error

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am attempting to use MultinomialNB from sklearn to classify some data. I have made a sample csv with some labelled training data, which I want to use to train the model but I receive the following error message:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[0 1 2 2].
```

I know it is a very small data set but I will eventually add more data once the code is working.

Here is my data:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import array as array
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
data_file = pd.read_csv("CSV_Labels.csv", engine='python')
data_file.tail()
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
all_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(data_file.Word)
all_features.shape
x_train = data_file.label
y_train = data_file.Word
x_train.values.reshape(1, -1)
y_train.values.reshape(1, -1)
classifer = MultinomialNB()
classifer.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
x_train = x_train.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = y_train.values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

`numpy` reshape operations are not inplace. So the array's you're passing to the classifier have actual the old shapes.

Comment: Hello Tinu Thanks so much for your help! Sorry it was such a silly question. I've amended the code but I am now getting the following error: ValueError: bad input shape (1, 4). Could it be an issue with the format of my csv?

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. Actually I made a mistake there. The way you reshape the vectors makes them row vectors, but the classifier likes to have columns vectors. I edited my answer accordingly.